# dynamically created column in listview using vb6

Tags: listview, vb6

> is it possible to add column in listview while the program is running?

i'am using vb6.

this is my code but i got error in EOF maybe because i don't used any databases because i don't need it.

```
Do While a.EOF
Set itmX = ListView2.ListItems.Add(, , Text2)
                    itmX.SubItems(1) = Text2.Text
                    itmX.SubItems(2) = Text2
Loop
```

i know it's wrong that's why i need you help.. :) thank you in advance

Comment: What is 'a'? A recordset? A file? Include more code please.

Comment: Also, what the code above says is this:
While end of file for 'a' is True run the following code
Which will result in a overflow error because it is an infinite loop